# Token Based Auth SecurityContextHolder is not null sometimes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jwt, access-token

I have Token based authorization,
Well thing i faced is that after authentication i gain token and then  i try manually to  send calls to server without token and i refresh it fast and sometimes it allows me to get the data as somehow proper data of authorization is in `SecurityContextHolder` and don't know how it appeared there, when token wasn't sent to server, and yeah i use `STATELESS` Session

Here is my config:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws  Exception{
        AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new AuthenticationTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

AuthenticationTokenFilter

```
public class AuthenticationTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    @Autowired
    private TokenUtils tokenUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        tokenUtils = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext())
                .getBean(TokenUtils.class);
        userDetailsService = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext())
                .getBean(UserDetailsService.class);


        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, " + Constants.tokenHeader);


        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader(Constants.tokenHeader);

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(authToken != null){
            String username = this.tokenUtils.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
            if (username != null && auth == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                if (this.tokenUtils.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this springboot jwt starter.

Security config: https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bfwg/config/WebSecurityConfig.java

AuthenticationTokenFilter: https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bfwg/security/auth/TokenAuthenticationFilter.java

Hope this helps.